# How to get private variables of instance object without calling method

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to call a specific method (or getting instance variables) without instance method from instance object in Ruby?

```
class Foo
  def initialize(arg)
    @bar = arg
  end
end

f = Foo.new('test')
p f #=> "test" (in this case, get @bar variable without instance method)
```

---

For instance, if Example class is defined,

```
ex = Example.new
ex #=> #<Example:0x00000000000000>
```

I want to do, like this.

```
ex = Example.new('hello')
ex #=> "hello"
```

Comment: unclear what you're asking. What you want can be achieved my overriding the `to_s` method

Comment: you can use `attr_reader :bar` to get ruby to write the getter for you?

Comment: I want to get a value without instance method (including attr). For example, instance of String returns its value. When I call its initialize method `s = String.new('foo')` , I can access its value without instance method `s #=> 'foo'` .

Comment: Re-read your question: "how to call a method without a method". It doesn't make sense!

Comment: You're confusing two things together: string representation of an object and its actual value. These are very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inspect` for `p` and `to_s` for `puts`

```
class Foo
  def initialize(arg)
    @bar = arg
  end
  def inspect
    @bar
  end
  def to_s
    @bar
  end
end

f = Foo.new('test')
puts f #=> "test"
p f #=> "test"
```

Comment: For `p` you want `.inspect`

Comment: @YohsukeInoda no you can't use it everywhere: `p f.capitalize` results in a NoMethodError.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the `initialize` method is ignored; `initialize` always returns `self`, in this case an instance of Foo. Defining a `to_s` method just defines a string representation of the Foo instance.

```
f = Foo.new('test')

p f #=> "test"
p f.class #=> Foo
```

So after `ex = Example.new('hello')`, ex will always be a Example instance. It can not be a string or whatever.